# Animating view on UIKeyboardWillShowNotification event in iOS 8

Tags: ios, animation, notifications, keyboard, ios8

I am using following code to animate view's position according to keyboard movement. The code works fine under iOS 7, however it causes strange behaviour under iOS 8:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*) aNotification {  
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
    NSTimeInterval time = [keyboardInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [keyboardInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue];
    CGRect keyboardFrameEnd = [[keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    double offset = keyboardFrameEnd.size.width > keyboardFrameEnd.size.height ? keyboardFrameEnd.size.height : keyboardFrameEnd.size.width;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"moveWindow" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:time];

    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y + offset, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Unfortunately, the answers mentioned in [Is there a change to the behaviour of UIKeyboardWillShowNotification in iOS 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279753/is-there-a-change-to-the-behaviour-of-uikeyboardwillshownotification-in-ios-8) and [iOS8: What's going on with moving views during keyboard transitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112319/ios8-whats-going-on-with-moving-views-during-keyboard-transitions) are out of the question:

- The source code base is very large and old and use neither storyboard nor Auto Layout features.
- I don't want to use `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` event because the keyboard is already visible and the animation looks terrible (however, the problem is gone when using this type of notification).

Oddly enough, I found out that the problem is gone when the feature is used in the very first screen of the application. Further tests showed that removing `MKMapView` from one of the previous screens solves this issue. I triple checked that `MKMapView` is used and disposed correctly. Every allocated instance is gone way before the above code is executed.

After hours of testing and debugging I noticed in a visual hierarchy debugger ([How do I inspect the view hierarchy in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150186/how-do-i-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-in-ios)) that there are constraints added under `UILayoutContainerView` and `UINavigationTransitionView`. These constraints are not present when the `MKMapView` control is removed from the previous screen. I tried playing with every possible combination of `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:` setup and could not find any resolution yet. Is it some sort of bug in iOS 8 itself or is there another way to animate view along with the keyboard?

Comment: Can you show some code where you are creating the views. Specifically the code that you are changing when it "starts to work".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the code itself but from the documentation about those animation methods...

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

The correct way to animate you view is...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:time
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y + offset, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

**Edit**

OK, it's not AutoLayout (I think) but I'll leave this here anyway as you need to change it and I'll wait for more information in the question.